# How to custom library DB using Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want custom a few things in the library `db`...

And I created core system classes `MY_DB` in **application/core** folder:

```
class MY_DB extends CI_DB {
    public function __construct() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();
        $this->db = $CI->db;
    }

    public function get($table = '', $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL) {
        // my code custom...
        $this->db->get($table, $limit, $offset);
    }
    public function insert($table = '', $set = NULL) {
        // my code custom...
        $this->db->insert($table, $set);
    }
}
```

but apparently it does not work.

I want when I execute `$this->db->get()`, it will run the code I customized within class `MY_DB`.

If you just take a look at my problem and share a bit of your science, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, there is no core class named DB, therefore the override does not have to work. Secondly is your $config['subclass_prefix'] set to 'MY_'? No more ideas :/

Comment: I just found something. Have a look at this. So as I mentioned there is no core class named DB, you need to work it out from Loader class as in this example [https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers)

Comment: Yes, $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_' has been set as default

Comment: You need to create instance `$CI =& get_instance();` and use `$CI->db->get()`

Comment: I can do it (please see my edited), but apparently it does not work when I execute `$this->db->get()`

Comment: @jPO: Thanks for reply, but my problem is still unsolved!

Comment: See my answer to understand why the subclass_prefix is irrelevant ... @jPO Technically, there is a CI_DB class, but it is declared dynamically by a function.

Comment: May I propose another suggestion? Let's just say the name DB isn't that important. Therefore you can name your class let's say dbz or dbgt (both of them are good actually) and extending the base DB class you can access also the methods of the original class included in your class. Whatcha say?

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter (at this time, latest version 3.0.0) doesn't support extending its database classes like it does with other libraries. It's not impossible of course, but there's no official, built-into the framework  way to do it and you'll have to come up with your own hack for it.

Comment: Currently, I can only create new class (my custom is `extendDB`), through it, I can execute `$this->extendDB->get()`, but this one was very inconvenient when I only want `$this->db->get()`... I really do not want to intervene directly in the core, as this would not be good if I want to upgrade the core later, or if there is interference on the core, I want it to be limited at least. You have a simple way to solve the problem of me?

Comment: I am certainly not suggesting that you modify the framework's core yourself, but I can't tell you more than that ... it's too broad.